# How to fix max quantity for group of customer

Tags: customer, custom-options, customer-group

I just want to reverse the functionality which are given in the image or in magento.
how is it possible

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no customer-group-specific `Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart` in Magento. This only exists natively for `Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart`.

To create a similar "max allowed qty" feature, you will need to create an extension that does the following.

1. Create the necessary system configuration interface similar to the minimum qty options.
2. Override `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item::getMaxSaleQty()` to be similar to `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item::getMinSaleQty()` among possible other related functions, if any.

The above steps should give you a good start.

Answer (score 0):

There is that option in inventory on product edit page.

[image]

Which Magento version are you using?

Comment: This configuration is for all customers. OP needs customer groups taken into account.

Comment: I know the above suggestion., but i want restrict on customer group for max quantity. i am using magento ver. 1.9.0.1